# Creating a table with a single column and values in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to create a table with a single column  and some values of my choice in SAS:

My code so far is as follows:

[image]

When I run this code, I get the error message:

```
The macro macro1 generated CARDS (data lines) for the DATA step, 
which could cause incorrect results.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI - next time please copy/paste the code as text into the question, don't use images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datalines` is not supported in macro syntax.  If you have a macro generating this code, you'll have to find another way to do this - presumably, creating a text file and saving the contents of the datalines to that.

You also don't need the `delimiter` as the field is on different lines - line break is automatically a delimiter.

Comment: Makes sense. I've just created a little workaround. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should show the entire message.  As mentioned you can't use CARDS or PARMCARDS in a macro.

```
ERROR: The macro MACRO1 generated CARDS (data lines) for the DATA step, which could cause incorrect results.  The DATA step and the 
       macro will stop executing.
```